# Single letter with a different language

Tags: babel

in my report I have to write the city word Umeå once. I have included `\usepackage[english,swedish]{babel}` but the result is

[image]

Not exactly right :/ Is it possible to just write the letter Å without including Swedish in babel?

The packages used in the report is

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl} % A4 paper and 11pt font size
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[english,swedish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{changepage} 
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{sectsty} 
\allsectionsfont{\centering \normalfont\scshape} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
```

Comment: Your file is probably UTF-8 encoded and you have `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}`. Change `latin1` into `utf8`. No need to enable Swedish.

Comment: Sorry. I don't have that package. See my question amended with all the packages included in the document.

Comment: Then add `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`. And remove `swedish`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a minimal example reproducing the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
Umeå \textsc{Umeå}
\end{document}
```

The file was saved as UTF-8 and the output is

[image]

Change it to

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
Umeå \textsc{Umeå}
\end{document}
```

and you'll get

[image]

There is no need to load `babel-swedish` for typesetting the character `å`.

Comment: I changed but get compile error. "! Package babel Error: You haven't loaded the option swedish yet.

See the babel package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.3 \select@language{swedish}
                             
? "

Comment: @Orongo That's a temporary error, because you disabled a language. Remove the `.aux` file and retry.

Comment: question shows small caps.  should get equivalent result with what you've answered, but it would be nice to see it.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Added

Answer (score 1):

How about:
\r{a}

I don't think any package needed.
See: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Special_Characters#Escaped_codes

Comment: I'm against typesetting accented letters with TeX constructs. All systems understand UTF8 nowadays, and it's really painful to read such coding.

Comment: I can't find the letter I am looking for in the link.

Comment: @Orongo How about `\r{a}` or even better `\aa`? I can find that on the linked page.